# how to connect google form with db (sqldeveloper)

Tags: oracle, google-apps-script

I googled it a lot but I cannot resolve the problem
I made some survey with google form and I also made the table for gathering result with sqldeveloper
I found some blogs they said that I can use method on apps script.

I made apps script and I use method like this

```
function openDatabaseConnection() {
  var host = 'host';
  var port = 'port';
  var dbName = 'SID';
  var username = 'username';
  var password = 'psw';
  var url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID';

  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
  return conn;
}
```

GPT said xe would be Service name but I checked it is SID so It is not fault..

But there's Exception which is Exception: Invalid argument: url
openDatabaseConnection

If someone know how to connect google form result with database hope someone give me a hand

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is an IDE used to talk to databases; it is **NOT** a database and you cannot "connect" to SQL Developer from a third-party application. You need to connect directly to the database that Oracle SQL Developer is also talking to.